# Creating array of buttons

Tags: c, arrays, button, gtk, parameter-passing

Please help me to create array of buttons. This is what I did so far but I believe I'm doing smth wrong as my program doesn't run as it should.

```
/*array is here*/
GtkWidget *button[2];
int i;
for (i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    button[i]=gtk_button_new();
}

button[0] = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Run shellscript");

g_signal_connect (button[0], "clicked",
        G_CALLBACK (callback), "shellscript");

gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box1), button[0], TRUE, TRUE, 0);

gtk_widget_show(button[0]);

button[1] = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Run program2 ");

g_signal_connect (button[1], "clicked",
        G_CALLBACK (callback), "program2");

gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box1), button[1], TRUE, TRUE, 0);

gtk_widget_show(button[1]);
```

Comment: And _how_ should it run ? And how _does_ it run ?

Comment: Well basically it doesn't run at all, the reason is in array, because when I just used gtkWidget *button1; GtkWidget *button2; everything worked,,, now it doesn't with array

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to better indent the code you put in your question.

Comment: and how could your program run if it doesn't even compile ? I doubt that `For (i=...` compiles.

Comment: You have a *leak*. First you create a button and assign a pointer to it to each element of the array. Then you create *another* button and reassign the pointer in the array, making the first button you create with `gtk_new_button` in the loop inaccessible.

Comment: It compiles, and gives me executable but after that nothing happens, just blank...

Comment: @MichaelWalz it's for not For, sorry that was a typo.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so I shouldn't even use `gtk_new_button`... how do I finish my loop? Just with  `button [i];` ?

Comment: @AnastasiaNetz so you retyped your code instead of copy pasting it ??

Comment: The "For" typo proves you did not test what you posted. Posting a minimal sample of your code is good idea, but you need to make it a whole program, test it to check you have the same error than in your project, and post the whole MCVE in your question.

Comment: @AnastasiaNetz: An easier approach  might  have been 1. Create the buttons, 2. Add them to box  3. Add the box to toplevel windows. 4. Show window..

Comment: If you have low C knowledge, them post a complete source code that compiles reproducing your problem. Otherwise we can't know exactly what you did or omitted. For example I can't know if you called `gtk_init` or `gtk_main` from this sample, I don't know what you're doing in your callback, neither if you created a toplevel window and made it visible...

Comment: @jdarthenay I did test it btw, it's just when I pasted the code and when I was trying to add 4 spaces I deleted `f` from `for` by accident, and then when I typed it again it was capital and I didn't notice it...

Comment: @liberforce I was afraid to post the whole code, cuz this community sometimes doesn't like that. But here is my whole code:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784867/getting-an-error-xlib-extension-randr-missing-on-display-24-0-gtk

Comment: You don't need to manually add four spaces in front of each line of code. When writing your post, just select the whole code and click the "{}" button...

Comment: @jdarthenay trust ne I do it, but sometimes some lines still need to be adjusted:(

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

Your loop is useless, as your creating the buttons by hand afterwards, and creates a memory leak. Remove the whole block.

From your other code sample, I see that you don't call `gtk_widget_show_all` on your toplevel window. It works like `gtk_widget_show`, except that it's recursive, and will show the widget and all it children.

I could have your code sample run with these 2 modifications. However, the Xrandr error is totally unrelated and is relative to your environment. Check that you can run another GTK application without problem (like `gtk-demo`, installed with GTK).